# Turn OFF Chat Thumbnail

Tags: chatter, chat

Does anyone know how to turn OFF the Chat thumbnail at the right bottom of the screen in Salesforce Classic ?

I know we can turn this Chat thumbnail OFF because we also have a developer org that does not show up this thumbnail

Comment: Some of our users recently reported seeing this where they didn't use to see it before. When did you start seeing this?

Answer (score 2):

Enabling and Disabling Chat

Chat is enabled by default in organizations that have Chatter enabled.

1. Click Your Name | Setup | Customize | Chatter | Chat Settings.
2. Click Edit.
3. Under Chat Settings, select or deselect Enable Chat. Chatter must be enabled to enable chat.
4. Click Save.